# Accessed accelerometer readings not logical

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I followed [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/use-the-accelerometer), that receives and displays readings from a device's accelerometer. I tried the app on two devices while they are stationary on a table and get similar readings like:

> X-axis: 0.01
>
> Y-axis: -0.59
>
> Z-axis: -0.82

The code is exactly as in the article. What's wrong?

Comment: Is the Reading() method still being called periodically while the devices are stationary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readings come from the gravity field, with constant acceleration about ~9.81 [m/s2]. Depending on the phone's angle you will receive different values on each axle.

The phone's accelerometer shows [G-force](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer) values and `Z = -0.82` means that the phone (which means the table in this case) is not leveled.

Comment: Thx. I didn't consider gravity. When the device is level, one axis give a reading of |1| and the others are nearly 0 (| 0.02|).